# I need to loop over a big JSON - Pandas/Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a JSON file that looks like this:

```
[    {
            "id": 121,
            "name": "Lebanon",
            "iso3": "LBN",
            "iso2": "LB",
            "numeric_code": "422",
            "phone_code": "961",
            "capital": "Beirut",
            "currency": "LBP",
            "currency_name": "Lebanese pound",
            "currency_symbol": "£",
            "tld": ".lb",
            "native": "لبنان",
            "region": "Asia",
            "subregion": "Western Asia",
            "timezones": [
                {
                    "zoneName": "Asia\/Beirut",
                    "gmtOffset": 7200,
                    "gmtOffsetName": "UTC+02:00",
                    "abbreviation": "EET",
                    "tzName": "Eastern European Time"
                }
            ],
            "translations": {
                "kr": "레바논",
                "br": "Líbano",
                "pt": "Líbano",
                "nl": "Libanon",
                "hr": "Libanon",
                "fa": "لبنان",
                "de": "Libanon",
                "es": "Líbano",
                "fr": "Liban",
                "ja": "レバノン",
                "it": "Libano",
                "cn": "黎巴嫩",
                "tr": "Lübnan"
            },
            "latitude": "33.83333333",
            "longitude": "35.83333333",
            "emoji": "",
            "emojiU": "U+1F1F1 U+1F1E7",
            "states": [
                {
                    "id": 2285,
                    "name": "Akkar Governorate",
                    "state_code": "AK",
                    "latitude": "34.53287630",
                    "longitude": "36.13281320",
                    "type": null,
                    "cities": [
                        {
                            "id": 65939,
                            "name": "Caza de Aakkar",
                            "latitude": "34.53333000",
                            "longitude": "36.16667000"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": 2283,
                    "name": "Baalbek-Hermel Governorate",
                    "state_code": "BH",
                    "latitude": "34.26585560",
                    "longitude": "36.34980970",
                    "type": null,
                    "cities": [
                        {
                            "id": 65933,
                            "name": "Baalbek",
                            "latitude": "34.00583000",
                            "longitude": "36.21806000"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 65941,
                            "name": "Caza de Baalbek",
                            "latitude": "34.09822000",
                            "longitude": "36.27157000"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": 2286,
                    "name": "Beirut Governorate",
                    "state_code": "BA",
                    "latitude": "33.88861060",
                    "longitude": "35.49547720",
                    "type": null,
                    "cities": [
                        {
                            "id": 65936,
                            "name": "Beirut",
                            "latitude": "33.89332000",
                            "longitude": "35.50157000"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 65951,
                            "name": "Ra’s Bayrūt",
                            "latitude": "33.90000000",
                            "longitude": "35.48333000"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": 2287,
                    "name": "Beqaa Governorate",
                    "state_code": "BI",
                    "latitude": "33.84626620",
                    "longitude": "35.90194890",
                    "type": null,
                    "cities": [
                        {
                            "id": 65930,
                            "name": "Aanjar",
                            "latitude": "33.72778000",
                            "longitude": "35.93111000"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 65955,
                            "name": "Zahlé",
                            "latitude": "33.84675000",
                            "longitude": "35.90203000"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": 2282,
                    "name": "Mount Lebanon Governorate",
                    "state_code": "JL",
                    "latitude": "33.81008580",
                    "longitude": "35.59731390",
                    "type": null,
                    "cities": [
                        {
                            "id": 65932,
                            "name": "Baabda",
                            "latitude": "33.83389000",
                            "longitude": "35.54417000"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 65937,
                            "name": "Bhamdoun",
                            "latitude": "33.79500000",
                            "longitude": "35.65111000"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 65938,
                            "name": "Bhamdoûn el Mhatta",
                            "latitude": "33.80861000",
                            "longitude": "35.65972000"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 65940,
                            "name": "Caza de Baabda",
                            "latitude": "33.84592000",
                            "longitude": "35.66791000"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 65947,
                            "name": "Jbaïl",
                            "latitude": "34.12111000",
                            "longitude": "35.64806000"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 65948,
                            "name": "Jounieh",
                            "latitude": "33.98083000",
                            "longitude": "35.61778000"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": 2288,
                    "name": "Nabatieh Governorate",
                    "state_code": "NA",
                    "latitude": "33.37716930",
                    "longitude": "35.48382930",
                    "type": null,
                    "cities": [
                        {
                            "id": 65931,
                            "name": "Ain Ebel",
                            "latitude": "33.11023000",
                            "longitude": "35.40251000"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 65942,
                            "name": "Caza de Bent Jbaïl",
                            "latitude": "33.15964000",
                            "longitude": "35.41137000"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 65943,
                            "name": "Caza de Nabatîyé",
                            "latitude": "33.39435000",
                            "longitude": "35.44483000"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 65946,
                            "name": "Habboûch",
                            "latitude": "33.40729000",
                            "longitude": "35.48169000"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 65949,
                            "name": "Marjayoûn",
                            "latitude": "33.36028000",
                            "longitude": "35.59111000"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 65950,
                            "name": "Nabatîyé et Tahta",
                            "latitude": "33.37889000",
                            "longitude": "35.48389000"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": 2284,
                    "name": "North Governorate",
                    "state_code": "AS",
                    "latitude": "34.43806250",
                    "longitude": "35.83082330",
                    "type": null,
                    "cities": [
                        {
                            "id": 65934,
                            "name": "Batroûn",
                            "latitude": "34.25528000",
                            "longitude": "35.65806000"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 65935,
                            "name": "Bcharré",
                            "latitude": "34.25083000",
                            "longitude": "36.01056000"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 65953,
                            "name": "Tripoli",
                            "latitude": "34.43352000",
                            "longitude": "35.84415000"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": 2281,
                    "name": "South Governorate",
                    "state_code": "JA",
                    "latitude": "33.27214790",
                    "longitude": "35.20327780",
                    "type": null,
                    "cities": [
                        {
                            "id": 65944,
                            "name": "En Nâqoûra",
                            "latitude": "33.11806000",
                            "longitude": "35.13972000"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 65945,
                            "name": "Ghazieh",
                            "latitude": "33.51750000",
                            "longitude": "35.36889000"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 65952,
                            "name": "Sidon",
                            "latitude": "33.55751000",
                            "longitude": "35.37148000"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 65954,
                            "name": "Tyre",
                            "latitude": "33.27333000",
                            "longitude": "35.19389000"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
]
```

How can I access `states` > `name` ?

For example, I need `Akkar Governorate` from

```
    "states": [
                    {
                        "id": 2285,
                        "name": "Akkar Governorate",
                        "state_code": "AK",
                        "latitude": "34.53287630",
                        "longitude": "36.13281320",
                        "type": null,
                        "cities": [
                            {
                                "id": 65939,
                                "name": "Caza de Aakkar",
                                "latitude": "34.53333000",
                                "longitude": "36.16667000"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
]
```

How can I manage a loop to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
yourJsonObj = json.loads("your json string")
   for key, val in yourJsonObj
       Access/Manipulate data
```

Here are more examples:
[JSON Read, write, parse](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/json)
Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! But I'm getting this error `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`

Comment: Oh that's very strange, can you break the json up at all before processing?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to:

```
with open(r"C:\Users\Bar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts\contries+states+cities.json", encoding="utf8") as f:
       data = json.loads(f.read())
```

You can read name like this:

```
data[0]['states'][1]['name'] #hierarchy way
```

also you can even perform following kind of Coding:

```
def get_data(name):
    for i in range(len( data[0]['states'])):
        if data[0]['states'][i]['name'] == name:
            print(data[0]['states'][i])
        
get_data('Akkar Governorate')
```

Comment: Thanks. But I'm getting this error

`KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-c027431a4535> in <module>
----> 1 data[0]['states'][1]['name']
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2895                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   2896             except KeyError as err:
-> 2897                 raise KeyError(key) from err
   2898 
   2899         if tolerance is not None:

KeyError: 0`

Comment: Hi @LanaStance I have update the code, please try again.

Comment: I'm still getting the same error :(

Comment: Hey @LanaStance Can you update your question with your try and error?

Comment: I did post a new post. Please visit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72559700/i-need-to-loop-over-a-big-list-of-jsons-pandas-python and thank you !!

Comment: Hi @LanaStance I please refer the updated code, and if you find helpful please up vote.