# I need to loop over a big list of JSONs - Pandas/Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a big JSON file like the following:

```
[
   {
      "id":121,
      "name":"Lebanon",
      "iso3":"LBN",
      "iso2":"LB",
      "numeric_code":"422",
      "phone_code":"961",
      "capital":"Beirut",
      "currency":"LBP",
      "currency_name":"Lebanese pound",
      "currency_symbol":"£",
      "tld":".lb",
      "native":"لبنان",
      "region":"Asia",
      "subregion":"Western Asia",
      "timezones":[
         {
            "zoneName":"Asia\/Beirut",
            "gmtOffset":7200,
            "gmtOffsetName":"UTC+02:00",
            "abbreviation":"EET",
            "tzName":"Eastern European Time"
         }
      ],
      "translations":{
         "kr":"레바논",
         "br":"Líbano",
         "pt":"Líbano",
         "nl":"Libanon",
         "hr":"Libanon",
         "fa":"لبنان",
         "de":"Libanon",
         "es":"Líbano",
         "fr":"Liban",
         "ja":"レバノン",
         "it":"Libano",
         "cn":"黎巴嫩",
         "tr":"Lübnan"
      },
      "latitude":"33.83333333",
      "longitude":"35.83333333",
      "emoji":"",
      "emojiU":"U+1F1F1 U+1F1E7",
      "states":[
         {
            "id":2285,
            "name":"Akkar Governorate",
            "state_code":"AK",
            "latitude":"34.53287630",
            "longitude":"36.13281320",
            "type":null,
            "cities":[
               {
                  "id":65939,
                  "name":"Caza de Aakkar",
                  "latitude":"34.53333000",
                  "longitude":"36.16667000"
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "id":2283,
            "name":"Baalbek-Hermel Governorate",
            "state_code":"BH",
            "latitude":"34.26585560",
            "longitude":"36.34980970",
            "type":null,
            "cities":[
               {
                  "id":65933,
                  "name":"Baalbek",
                  "latitude":"34.00583000",
                  "longitude":"36.21806000"
               },
               {
                  "id":65941,
                  "name":"Caza de Baalbek",
                  "latitude":"34.09822000",
                  "longitude":"36.27157000"
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "id":2286,
            "name":"Beirut Governorate",
            "state_code":"BA",
            "latitude":"33.88861060",
            "longitude":"35.49547720",
            "type":null,
            "cities":[
               {
                  "id":65936,
                  "name":"Beirut",
                  "latitude":"33.89332000",
                  "longitude":"35.50157000"
               },
               {
                  "id":65951,
                  "name":"Ra’s Bayrūt",
                  "latitude":"33.90000000",
                  "longitude":"35.48333000"
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "id":2287,
            "name":"Beqaa Governorate",
            "state_code":"BI",
            "latitude":"33.84626620",
            "longitude":"35.90194890",
            "type":null,
            "cities":[
               {
                  "id":65930,
                  "name":"Aanjar",
                  "latitude":"33.72778000",
                  "longitude":"35.93111000"
               },
               {
                  "id":65955,
                  "name":"Zahlé",
                  "latitude":"33.84675000",
                  "longitude":"35.90203000"
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "id":2282,
            "name":"Mount Lebanon Governorate",
            "state_code":"JL",
            "latitude":"33.81008580",
            "longitude":"35.59731390",
            "type":null,
            "cities":[
               {
                  "id":65932,
                  "name":"Baabda",
                  "latitude":"33.83389000",
                  "longitude":"35.54417000"
               },
               {
                  "id":65937,
                  "name":"Bhamdoun",
                  "latitude":"33.79500000",
                  "longitude":"35.65111000"
               },
               {
                  "id":65938,
                  "name":"Bhamdoûn el Mhatta",
                  "latitude":"33.80861000",
                  "longitude":"35.65972000"
               },
               {
                  "id":65940,
                  "name":"Caza de Baabda",
                  "latitude":"33.84592000",
                  "longitude":"35.66791000"
               },
               {
                  "id":65947,
                  "name":"Jbaïl",
                  "latitude":"34.12111000",
                  "longitude":"35.64806000"
               },
               {
                  "id":65948,
                  "name":"Jounieh",
                  "latitude":"33.98083000",
                  "longitude":"35.61778000"
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "id":2288,
            "name":"Nabatieh Governorate",
            "state_code":"NA",
            "latitude":"33.37716930",
            "longitude":"35.48382930",
            "type":null,
            "cities":[
               {
                  "id":65931,
                  "name":"Ain Ebel",
                  "latitude":"33.11023000",
                  "longitude":"35.40251000"
               },
               {
                  "id":65942,
                  "name":"Caza de Bent Jbaïl",
                  "latitude":"33.15964000",
                  "longitude":"35.41137000"
               },
               {
                  "id":65943,
                  "name":"Caza de Nabatîyé",
                  "latitude":"33.39435000",
                  "longitude":"35.44483000"
               },
               {
                  "id":65946,
                  "name":"Habboûch",
                  "latitude":"33.40729000",
                  "longitude":"35.48169000"
               },
               {
                  "id":65949,
                  "name":"Marjayoûn",
                  "latitude":"33.36028000",
                  "longitude":"35.59111000"
               },
               {
                  "id":65950,
                  "name":"Nabatîyé et Tahta",
                  "latitude":"33.37889000",
                  "longitude":"35.48389000"
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "id":2284,
            "name":"North Governorate",
            "state_code":"AS",
            "latitude":"34.43806250",
            "longitude":"35.83082330",
            "type":null,
            "cities":[
               {
                  "id":65934,
                  "name":"Batroûn",
                  "latitude":"34.25528000",
                  "longitude":"35.65806000"
               },
               {
                  "id":65935,
                  "name":"Bcharré",
                  "latitude":"34.25083000",
                  "longitude":"36.01056000"
               },
               {
                  "id":65953,
                  "name":"Tripoli",
                  "latitude":"34.43352000",
                  "longitude":"35.84415000"
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "id":2281,
            "name":"South Governorate",
            "state_code":"JA",
            "latitude":"33.27214790",
            "longitude":"35.20327780",
            "type":null,
            "cities":[
               {
                  "id":65944,
                  "name":"En Nâqoûra",
                  "latitude":"33.11806000",
                  "longitude":"35.13972000"
               },
               {
                  "id":65945,
                  "name":"Ghazieh",
                  "latitude":"33.51750000",
                  "longitude":"35.36889000"
               },
               {
                  "id":65952,
                  "name":"Sidon",
                  "latitude":"33.55751000",
                  "longitude":"35.37148000"
               },
               {
                  "id":65954,
                  "name":"Tyre",
                  "latitude":"33.27333000",
                  "longitude":"35.19389000"
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

I did load it into a data frame
[image]
The goal is to analyze a text, and find if the text contains a location related to one of these (name, capital, states).

So, if the word in the text was `*kabul*` so it is `*afghanistan*`. Same for `states`, if the word was in the `states` column I want to assign it to its country `name`.

I can access `name` and `capital`. But how to access `states`?

**How to access `states` > `name`? Example from the above JSON:
`Akkar Governorate`, `Baalbek-Hermel Governorate`.**

Comment: So the only columns you'll be working with are 'name', 'capital' and 'state'? Because in your screenshot the columns are cut off. 

Can you create and upload the data frame of all the columns you intend to use?

Comment: @nizarhamood True. using



`new_dataframe = df[['name', 'capital', 'states']].copy()
new_dataframe.head(1)` will have the required columns. But I need to deal with `states` > `name`. https://i.ibb.co/pjLDKDc/2022-06-09-145642.png

Answer (score 1):

To get all values in **states > name** with a row number for easy access to values in other columns.

```
names = [(index, name['name']) for index, states in enumerate(new_dataframe["states"]) for name in states]
```

**Output using given sample JSON**:

```
[(0, 'Akkar Governorate'), (0, 'Baalbek-Hermel Governorate'), (0, 'Beirut Governorate'), (0, 'Beqaa Governorate'), (0, 'Mount Lebanon Governorate'), (0, 'Nabatieh Governorate'), (0, 'North Governorate'), (0, 'South Governorate')]
```

You can easily search for these tuples and also get the row number to use in other columns like name and capital etc.

**Update:** (Just a workaround) You can use this to get state->name and state->cities->name with all combinations.

```
names = [(index, name['name'], city['name']) for index, states in enumerate(new_dataframe["states"])
         for name in states for city in name['cities']]
```

**Output:**

```
[(0, 'Akkar Governorate', 'Caza de Aakkar'), (0, 'Baalbek-Hermel Governorate', 'Baalbek'), (0, 'Baalbek-Hermel Governorate', 'Caza de Baalbek'), (0, 'Beirut Governorate', 'Beirut'), (0, 'Beirut Governorate', 'Ra’s Bayrūt'), (0, 'Beqaa Governorate', 'Aanjar'), (0, 'Beqaa Governorate', 'Zahlé'), (0, 'Mount Lebanon Governorate', 'Baabda'), (0, 'Mount Lebanon Governorate', 'Bhamdoun'), (0, 'Mount Lebanon Governorate', 'Bhamdoûn el Mhatta'), (0, 'Mount Lebanon Governorate', 'Caza de Baabda'), (0, 'Mount Lebanon Governorate', 'Jbaïl'), (0, 'Mount Lebanon Governorate', 'Jounieh'), (0, 'Nabatieh Governorate', 'Ain Ebel'), (0, 'Nabatieh Governorate', 'Caza de Bent Jbaïl'), (0, 'Nabatieh Governorate', 'Caza de Nabatîyé'), (0, 'Nabatieh Governorate', 'Habboûch'), (0, 'Nabatieh Governorate', 'Marjayoûn'), (0, 'Nabatieh Governorate', 'Nabatîyé et Tahta'), (0, 'North Governorate', 'Batroûn'), (0, 'North Governorate', 'Bcharré'), (0, 'North Governorate', 'Tripoli'), (0, 'South Governorate', 'En Nâqoûra'), (0, 'South Governorate', 'Ghazieh'), (0, 'South Governorate', 'Sidon'), (0, 'South Governorate', 'Tyre')]
```

Comment: This is Amazing! But it is hard for me to complete the goal. I want the cities too. I mean `states` > `name` > `cities` > `name` I want to group all of them to the main country. That is my goal. Please help me in this.